# Cherokee access-log for specific file

Tags: cherokee

**Context:** I'm monitoring an APT repository mirror server, who runs on Cherokee.
**Goal:** know how many computers have the mirror in their sources.list
**Method:** tracking GET requests for "dists/[..]/Release"
For Debian Wheezy, this would be dists/wheezy/Release.

Extracting the lines from the general access log won't be doable, the mirror is enough used to make the accesslog grow to 2 GB in just a few days. Just wanna know how many different IPs use the APT mirror, and Perl regular expressions are still a pain in the ass for me.

Is it possible to make Cherokee only logging access matching a request criteria (and how) ?

**Fallback solution:** what kind of redirect could pass the "Release" GET to a PHP script (who can sha1 hash the IP address and put as filename in a folder, quite easy counting), who then redirects back to the actual Release file ? (without redirect looping, and with the mirroring rsync in mind who has to reset this after each sync)

Answer (score 0):

Using cherokee-admin you can add a Behavior Rule that matches the "dists/[..]/Release" requests. You then go to "vServers/Behavior/Rule Management" and on the "Security" tab you check the "Skip Logging" option, disabling the logging for all rules except the one you've added.

> what kind of redirect could pass the "Release" GET to a PHP script (who can sha1 hash the IP address and put as filename in a folder, quite easy counting), who then redirects back to the actual Release file ?

PHP can send the X-Sendfile (or X-Accel-Redirect) header, telling Cherokee to send the Release file.